# Google Data Studio: How to enable authentication for API connector using 2 KEYS

Tags: looker-studio, connector, api-authorization

I am trying to write a connector in GDS for a web service API. The API authentication method uses 2 KEYS (passed in the header): `X-App-Key` and `X-User-Key`

A 2-key auth flow doesn't fit into the 5 authentication options available in my `.gs` connector script. Do I implement a custom authentication method (don't see how) or modify `USER_PASS` or `USER_TOKEN` to accept the 2 keys?

***Update***: I am starting in on connecting another service and this one uses `API_TOKEN` and `API_SECRET`. Again, I don't see which of the 5 authentication types fit.

I assume this is a common issue being that there are so many different API's out there...

Answer (score 0):

Data Studio Community Connectors does not support any authentication method that requires 2 authentication keys in addition to username. Feel free to [open an issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues?q=componentid:321382) requesting this feature. We check those issues when decided on new features to add to the product.

You might want to look into `OAUTH2` as an option if you require a custom authentication method. You might be able to get that to work for your needs.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't really an answer, rather a workaround. I decided to build sheets/scripts to retrieve the data I needed from different APIs. I am in the middle of the project now, but so far it appears that my authentication issues are mitigated using google script with google sheets.